# can not close libvlcsharp popup in wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, libvlcsharp

this is my first question on stackoverflow.. i have some problem with libvlcsharp :
when i put vlcsharp mediaElement into a popup (like below code) and run the application , vlcsharp will add 3 button on the top ,right corner of popup : minimize , maximize and close.
minimize and maximize works fine but when i click on close button nothing happen.
the actual code  :

```
<popup>
<wpf:VideoView  x:Name="myVideoControl" MediaPlayer="{Binding MediaPlayer}"  />
</popup>
```

screenshot from popup :
[libvlcsharp popup screenshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhhUn.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the Popup is visible before calling Play, otherwise VLC will create its own window (D3D11 window)

Comment: thanks for the answer .
yes, the title of popup is "d3d11"( and i will try your advice) . 
but my question is that : "why close button of popup(wich created by vlc) does not work, should i handle any event or something ? or it's behave just like that ?

Comment: Might be a deadlock or something. That behavior shouldn't be used anyway as you can't really handle the window events